# How to store and access data on eventBus in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-bus

Basically I want to be able to access some centralized data by setting up a dataBus as a vue instance object, and then access and tweak this data from different components.

I cant seems to access by data from my componenets, even basic string interpolation is not getting rendered to the DOM.

```
  export const dataBus = new Vue({
    data: {
      numQuotes: 4,
      stringVar: 'Hellow There'
    }
  });
```

I also tried setting up my data as the return of the function data().  But being as my data bus is an actual vue instance I don't think this is correct.  (I could be wrong).  Following is the component in which I import my dataBus and try to output my data.

```
  <template>
    <div>
      <h1>Quotes Added</h1>
      <div id="trackerBar">
        <div id="trackerBarActual">
            <h2>{{numQuotes}}/10</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    import { dataBus } from '../main.js';

    export default{

    }
  </script>
```

I am getting the following error:  *Property or method "numQuotes" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.*

Am I missing something obvious?  Is it even possible to access data this way?  Or do I have to access it as a method?

Comment: You might be interested in [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for centralised state maintenance

Comment: I think you may be right, I havn't gotten to that chapter yet.

No way to store on eventBus then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the part where you assign `data` to your component. Try

```
<script>
import { dataBus } from '../main.js';

export default{
  data () {
    return dataBus.$data
  }
}
</script>
```

---

You should definitely look into [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for state management though.

Comment: Here is what Vue documentation says about this approach:

"Every component instance has its own isolated scope. This means you cannot (and should not) directly reference parent data in a child component’s template. Data can be passed down to child components using props."

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

Comment: @Vladimir This is completely different to parent / child component data passing. OP wants to share data from a separate Vue instance.

Comment: Data is still referenced and should not be used like this. Event bus / data bus is a separate vue instance and he should access data in it by using props. This video tutorials should help:

1. [Vue JS 2 Tutorial #25 - The Event Bus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzh4zQcfB0o), 
2. [COMPONENT COMMUNICATION (PROPS / EVENTS) | VueJS 2 | Learning the Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPmg7ntQjzc)

Comment: @Vladimir given an event / data bus is not mounted, just how would you propose to use props? In any case, OP was having a problem and this was the answer. If you think they should do it differently, perhaps you could post your own answer instead of downvoting mine

Comment: maybe you should learn how to use emitters, events and callback functions with props before you start to tear frameworks apart. If the documentation says that you shouldn't directly reference $data from another vue instance (data bus in this case), then you shouldn't. Reason may simply be that it will break compatibility with future versions of Vue. Using props is a tedious work without vuex, but at least it is a correct one. For your convenience, I have left two tutorials where you can learn how to do that.